# How do i make the terrain texture less repeating?

Tags: shaders, textures, godot

question in the title no more to add, don't say "but it depends on how you set up your project" cause i'll set up my project how i need to set it up to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: A couple suggestions for the texture itself, not godot specific: 1. Use textures that don't have distinctive features that can be easily noticed in repetition. 2. Use larger textures and map them to a greater number of terrain units. 3. Modify your one texture into a few variants that are all seamless with each other and use them randomly somehow (kind of like randomized tiles).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNuDkDhadfU&list=PLRL3Z3lpLmH3PNGZuDNf2WXnLTHpN9hXy&index=5&pp=iAQB

Comment: I halfway remember a method that involves drawing the same texture, but enlarged, as a kind of an overlay, preferably a couple of this at different frequencies, but I cannot for the life of me remember what it was called